# Remove event listener inside an element

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

**Checkout the code...**

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((element) => {

  element.addEventListener("keypress", respondToClick);
  function respondToClick() {
    console.log("Key Pressed");
    console.log(element);
  }

});

/*
'I don't know where to put...'

// RemoveEventListener
const removeEvent = () => {
  element.removeEventListener("click", respondToClick);
};

*/


// On HTML file
<button onclick="removeEvent();" class="numbers">RemoveEventListener</button>;
```

Can I add `removeEventListner` button that will remove an eventListner inside an element?

Comment: You can add a css class that has pointer-events: none; to that element

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way without inline JS (more info on [why to not do it](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-idl-attributes))

here's more info on [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) on MDN

```js
function respondToClick(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  console.log("Key Pressed:", event.key);
  console.log(element);
}

function removeEvent(event) {
  const element = event.target;
  element.removeEventListener("keypress", respondToClick)
}

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('keypress', respondToClick);
  element.onclick = removeEvent;
});
```

```html
<button>removeEventListener</button>
```